# Displaying single vowel or consonant with Kotex package

Tags: cjk

The latex example below states my question.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{kotex}
\begin{document}
I would like to display the consonants ㅇ and ㄹ along with the vowel ㅣ of the letter 일.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know nothing about Korean, and the `kotex` package is documented only in that language, but looking at the style file and the example  documents in the documentation,  it seems that it supports XeLaTeX, (with the `hangul` option). This means you can just type the characters directly into your source document:

```
% compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\usepackage[hangul]{kotex}
\setmainhangulfont{NanumMyeongjo}
\begin{document}
I would like to display the consonants ㅇ and ㄹ along with the vowel ㅣ of the letter 일.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I don't know...but it seems to me that typing out `\usepackage{kotex}` would seem to exclude half of the potential LaTeX community. `;^)`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Maybe it's for use with the [new engine the Salvation Army in Reykjavik seems to be developing.](https://goo.gl/qphlm4).